# How to disable future dates in daterangepicker

Tags: jquery, daterangepicker

I am using [this](http://www.daterangepicker.com/) plugin for selecting date range,
The configuration is my js is as follows:

```
// date range picker
$('.date_input').daterangepicker({
    autoUpdateInput: false,
    locale: {
        cancelLabel: 'Clear',
        format: 'DD-MM-YY'
    }
});
```

I need to disable the future dates, i tried using maxDate, but it did not work.
Please help me to resolve this issue.Help would be much appreciated
Thanks!!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, exactly, and what have you done? What does "did not work" mean?

Comment: I was trying to disable/ restrict the user to select the future dates (that is dates after today should not be selectable), so I user maxDate property, but since I was writing this maxDate property in locale {} property, so that maxDate was not working, later I saw that its a seperate property and not to be included in locale {}.

Comment: Details like this should be in the body of the question. Just edit the question and out them in.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use `maxDate` [options](http://www.daterangepicker.com/#options)

> (Date object, moment object or string) The latest date a user may select

```
$('.date_input').daterangepicker({
    maxDate: new Date()
})
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually setting "0" to maxDate will disable ALL dates not just the future ones. To disable all future days from NOW on, the right way is:

```
$('.date_input').daterangepicker({
    maxDate: moment()
})
```

Comment: Good solution. +1 from me. But remember, this works only if you have moment.js referenced in your project.

Answer (score 1):

Setting `"0"` to `maxDate` will disable all future dates

```
$('.date_input').daterangepicker({
    maxDate: "0"
})
```